# Socks not covering the ankles

Tags: wudu, clothing

My question is if socks that do not cover the ankles are allowed for men to wear while praying or just wearing them in normall occassions including wuduu or known as ablution. Please answer my question because I am confused.

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't be allowed, what prior effort have you done to answer your request? (see [ask])

Answer (score 1):

If you are wearing [Ihram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ihram) then you should not wear socks which covers you ankles

https://sunnah.com/urn/407230

Otherwise, i think its ok to wear because i don't found any restriction and when there is no restriction then its Up to you

Hope it helps you